# How to store offline form data in pouchDB?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm getting error while trying to insert data in pouch db.
I'm perform basic crud ops by seeing your video in youtube.
But getting this error while retreiving table

**Uncaught TypeError: db.alldocs is not a function**

I'm new to one page applications.

Here is my code

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>APP</title>

        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/3.5.0/pouchdb.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        var db = new PouchDB('courts');
        function searchCase(){
            var caseno = window.document.courtform.caseno.value;
            var casetype = window.document.courtform.casetype.value;
            var year = window.document.courtform.year.value;

            var store={
                    _id: caseno,
                    type: casetype,
                    yr: year


            };
            db.put(store, function callback(error,result)
            {
                if(!error){
                    clearfields();
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
                        "succesfully added";
                }
                alert("success");
            });
        }
        function showCase(){
            db.alldocs({include_docs: true, descending: true},
                    function(err,doc){

                showTableofCases(doc.rows);
                } );
             function showTableofCases(data){
                var div = document.getElementById("message");
                var str="<table border='1' align= 'center'><tr><th>xxx</th>"+

                "<th>vvv</th><th>hhh</th></tr>";
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    str+= "<tr><td>"+data[i].doc._id+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.type+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.year+"</td></tr>";
                }
                str+="</table>";
                div.innerHTML = str;

             }

        }
        function clearfields(){
            window.document.courtform.caseno.value="";
            window.document.courtform.casetype.value="";
            window.document.courtform.year.value="";
        }
 </script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <form name="courtform">

     <div align="center">
                     Case No<br/><input type="text" name="caseno" /><br/><br/>
                       Case Type
                        <select id="casetype" name="casetype" >
                            <option value="1" selected>WA</option><option value="2">WP</option><option value="3">SA</option><option value="4">AS</option></select><br/><br/>

                        Case Year<select id="year" name="year" >
                            <option value="0">2015</option>
                            <option value="1">2016</option>

                        </select><br/><br/>


                <input type="button"  value="Save" onclick="searchCase()" />

                <input type="button" value="show" onclick="showCase()" />

                            <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearfields()"/> 

           </div> </form>
           <div id="message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tell me where am igoi wrong???
Morover i'm pleased that the person who created this new tech has responded to my query....thats gr8!!!!
Thx in advance!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create autocomplete forum using html5 local storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351143/how-to-create-autocomplete-forum-using-html5-local-storage)

Comment: You'll get more help with this if you tag and title it properly. PouchDB is not HTML5 Local Storage, and nothing to do with HTML. It is an open source JavaScript database, and StackOverflow has it's own tag for it. So put PouchDB in your title, and change the tag to PouchDB, and you may get some answers.

Answer (score 4):

The error is that 1) you are `put()ing` a document without an `_id`, and 2) the document has a variable starting with `_` (`_case`). This is not allowed in PouchDB; the only valid identifiers starting with `_` are `_id`, `_rev`, and `_attachments`.

Also, if you had `console.log`ed the error in the callback to `put()`, then you would have seen the errors:

```
{ status: 412, 
  name: "missing_id", 
  message: "_id is required for puts", 
  error: true }
{ status: 500, 
  name: "doc_validation", 
  message: "Bad special document member: _case", 
  error: true, 
  reason: "_case" }
```

This is unfortunately a common mistake when writing asynchronous code! You should always handle the errors and print them out. :)

Comment: Please respond to my query as i changed it as per your       **tutorial** here

[PouchDB jump start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzuQ5tjh9X0)

Comment: Your new error is that you want to type `db.allDocs`, not `db.alldocs`. BTW we are usually pretty responsive on the #pouchdb IRC channel, so you may want to try that if you need more help. :) (click the "IRC" link at the bottom of http://pouchdb.com/)